# Why are piezoelectric transducers coated with electrodes on top and bottom?

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics, piezoelectric

I am learning about piezoelectric transducers and I want to know why the piezoelectric material is coated with electrodes in top and bottom ?

Comment: Well, how do you expect to get a signal out with just one contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I never asked my self the question before so this answer is something that sounds right to me but I didn't check it out. (not 100% sure)

The answer is to apply a voltage. Piezoelectric materials are most of the time electrically insulating, meaning "rubbing" significant charge on them will be difficult. But, electrodes attached will help applying the voltage by creating charge distributions on the electrodes themselves.

Answer (score 2):

those electrodes pick up the charge that is generated by flexure of the piezoelectric wafer and convey it as a tiny current to the wires that are soldered onto the electrodes.